# Required field validator doesn´t work

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms, requiredfieldvalidator

I have this code in my ASPX view:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDate"  runat="server" class="form-control" type="text"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator  id="rfvDate" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtDate" ErrorMessage="Obligatory field" ViewStateMode="Enabled" CssClass="alert-danger"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </div>
```

the error message appears correctly when I leave the field empty, but I also want to show an error message when the date is not correctly, I do this in my code behind but it doesn´t work:

```
 Private Sub Mybutton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Mybutton.Click
 If IsDate(txtDate.Text.ToString) = False Then
                rfvDate.IsValid = False
                rfvDate.Visible = True
                rfvDate.ErrorMessage = "Check that it is a valid date"
                Exit Sub

            Else
        'DO THE REST OF THE CODE
End Sub
```

What am I doing wrong? thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can use both  **RequiredField Validator** along with **RegularExpressionValidator**

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtDate" ValidationExpression="(((0|1)[1-9]|2[1-9]|3[0-1])\/(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/((19|20)\d\d))$"
    ErrorMessage="Invalid date format." CssClass="alert-danger" ValidationGroup="Group1" />
```

Add the `ValidationGroup="Group1"` to the Button aspx markup

Comment: With your code do not work the requiredfieldvalidator

Comment: @Esraa_92 yes, please use RegEXp for date and try it

Comment: @Esrra use both validator. RegularExpressionValidator and RequiredFieldValidator. it will work for you.

Comment: @Esraa_92 got it, are you trying to say that if the field is left empty then go with karanpatel idea

Comment: I see that when I add an incorrect date  it works correctly, but when I leave it empty, doesn´t works. How can I solve this?

Comment: @Esraa_92 did you tried keeping both the validators like Requiredfield and Regularexpressionvalidator?

Comment: Yes I put both and it´s works, but I have to change the style because lines meet

Comment: @Esraa_92 styles means?

Comment: @Esraa_92 you can use `display=Dynamic` for dynamically adjust error message instead of changing style sheet. if this doesn't work then you have to change css.

Comment: For this is would be more correct to use a [CompareValidator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.comparevalidator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) setting the operator to DataTypeCheck and type set to Date.